# FreeType FT_Get_Glyph always returns error 18

Tags: c++, freetype2

Using [this tutorial](https://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/03/sven/freetype_tut/), I've set up the latest version of FreeType to work with OpenGL. The only problem - `FT_Get_Glyph` always returns error 18.

More specifically, this is what I do:

1. Call an initialization function using a font from `C:/Windows/Fonts/`
2. That function successfully sets up the `FT_Face` (no errors), ready to set up the display lists.

   ```
   FT_Library library;
   if (FT_Init_FreeType(&library)) 
   {
       std::cout << "FT_Init_FreeType noobed";
       throw std::runtime_error("FT_Init_FreeType noobed");
   }
   FT_Face face;
   if (FT_New_Face(library, fontname, 0, &face)) 
   {
       std::cout << "FT_New_Face noobed (fix your font file)";
       throw std::runtime_error("FT_New_Face noobed (fix your font file)");
   }

   // (h << 6 = h * 64)
   FT_Set_Char_Size(face, h << 6, h << 6, 96, 96);

   list_base = glGenLists(128);
   glGenTextures(128, textures);

   //This is where we actually create each of the fonts display lists.
   for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 128; i++)
       make_dlist(face, i, list_base, textures);
   ```
3. `FT_Load_Glyph` returns no error, however, `FT_Get_Glyph` returns error code 18.

   ```
   FT_Select_Charmap(face, ft_encoding_unicode); // make it unicode, seems to have no effect on the error
   std::cout << "Char index: " << FT_Get_Char_Index(face, ch) << "\n";
   if (FT_Load_Glyph(face, FT_Get_Char_Index(face, ch), FT_LOAD_DEFAULT))
   {
       std::cout << "FT_Load_Glyph noobed";
       throw std::runtime_error("FT_Load_Glyph noobed");
   }
   FT_Glyph glyph;
   FT_Error a = FT_Get_Glyph(face->glyph, &glyph);
   if (a)
   {
       std::cout << "FT_Get_Glyph noobed " << (int)ch << " code " << a << "\n";
       return;//throw std::runtime_error("FT_Get_Glyph noobed");
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   ...
   Char index: 95
   FT_Get_Glyph noobed 124 code 18
   Char index: 96
   FT_Get_Glyph noobed 125 code 18
   Char index: 97
   FT_Get_Glyph noobed 126 code 18
   Char index: 0
   FT_Get_Glyph noobed 127 code 18
   ```

[Their website](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-error_code_values.html) says the error is `unsupported glyph image format`, so I was assuming a different font would work. I tried Arial, Consolas, Lucida Console and even a font from the internet, to no avail. (The above output is from Arial.) The only thing in common with these fonts are being TrueType (.ttf).

After googling and searching here, apparently literally no one else has posted a thread about this error showing up constantly.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: I have no knowledge of FreeType. Maybe looking at the source of [FT_Get_Glyph()](https://github.com/aseprite/freetype2/blob/af89e445f8c44f133362e840553194a2144ab0d5/src/base/ftglyph.c#L363) helps? It checks `slot->format`, so I would have a look at `face->glyph->format` to see what the actual format is.

Comment: @zett42 FT_Get_Font_Format returns TrueType, face->glyph->format is 0 which seems like TrueType to me, according to the order the possible values are written in the API reference.